# Loading multiple CSV files into QGIS 2.10

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, csv, import, load-them-all-plugin

How can I load multiple CSV files into QGIS with Longitude/Latitude already included in it.

I downloaded the "Load Them All" plug-in, however, the result loaded was converted as text files and cannot be visualize on the map canvass. Any help?

Are there any available plug-ins that can load multiple CSV file that will work fine in QGIS?

Comment: You could ask for that feature at https://github.com/gacarrillor/loadthemall/issues Just open a new issue describing what would you like to have. It would be nice to add it to Load Them All.

Comment: How are the multiple csv files different from each other?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the following code in the **Python Console** to locate your csv files in a specified folder and load them as point shapefiles using their longitude/latitude fields. The code assumes:

- The csv file is comma-separated
- The longitude/latitude field names are `"x"` and `"y"` respectively
- The CRS of the loaded layers will be in EPSG:4326

But you can edit this:

```
import glob, os

# Define path to  directory of your csv files
path_to_csv = "C:/Users/You/Desktop/csv folder/"  

# Set current directory to path of csv files
os.chdir(path_to_csv)  
# Find each .csv file and load them as vector layers
for fname in glob.glob("*.csv"):  
    uri = "file:///" + path_to_csv + fname + "?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4326&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "x", "y")
    name = fname.replace('.csv', '')
    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, 'delimitedtext')
    #QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

---

In the new version o QGIS, the command `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)` was discountinued. The solution is still valid if we substitute the former line by:
         `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)`
Also you need to delete or comment the second line `from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry`

The solution works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks to all your comments...it really works except for the one's saved as .csvt files.

Comment: @wgs84 - Most welcome, glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You might need csvt files along your CSV files to tell QGIS where it should find the geometry.

The plugin might use `Add Vector layer` in the background, not `Add delimited text` which does some educated guess on the geometry columns.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool QGIS plugin that does so. It's name is [CSV Batch Import](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/csv_batch_import/).