# Loading multiple CSV in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, csv

I tried to use the same coding from [Loading Multiple CSV Files into QGIS 2.10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212910) to load multiples CSV in QGIS but in QGIS 3.6 and it does not work. The code provided in the above link was used and the following error shows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.6\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
>       exec(code, self.locals)
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "", line 13, in 
>   NameError: name 'QgsMapLayerRegistry' is not defined

I am new to python so I don't really know what is going on. =P

Maybe some changes in parameters or so? Was some function deprecated from Python 2.7 to 3?

How the answer from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212910/loading-multiple-csv-files-into-qgis-2-10) would need to look like now? To facilitate, this is the code:

```
import glob, os

# Define path to  directory of your csv files
path_to_csv = "C:/Users/You/Desktop/csv folder/"  

# Set current directory to path of csv files
os.chdir(path_to_csv)  

# Find each .csv file and load them as vector layers
for fname in glob.glob("*.csv"):  
uri = "file:///" + path_to_csv + fname + "? delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4326&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "x", "y")
name = fname.replace('.csv', '')
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, 'delimitedtext')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Maybe [this tutorial](http://chris35wills.github.io/multi_csv_into_qgis/) can shed some light on the issue for you. Please keep in mind that QGIS 3 runs Python 3 instead of 2.7, so some terms may have changed.

Comment: this code is for QGIS 2 and you are using QGIS 3 , I think! `QgsMapLayerRegistry` has been deprecated in favor of `QgsProject`