# How to import multiple .csv files as .shp into Qgis with CRS and z

Tags: pyqgis, csv, import, qgis-python-console

I am trying to load multiple (50) .csv files to Qgis as shp layers.
My files are in a specific CRS (EPSG: 32642) and are points in z,y,z.

I first looked for a plugin to do this and then decided to do it with the Python Console.

I tried to adapt [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70671368/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-into-qgis-3-22-2) and it loads them but only as tables, and no z.
[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212910/loading-multiple-csv-files-into-qgis-2-10) is also something I tried without any results; and I don't belive it is the right way as there is no specified CRS.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need your csv files to remain as separate shapefiles? If not and your csv files all have the same headers e.g. X,Y,Z

It might be possible for you to combine these files into one using something like this:

```
from glob2 import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

dirpath = r"where all your csv files are"
outpath = r"where you would like the output saved"

files = [y for x in os.walk(dirpath) for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*csv'))]
print(files)


df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, files), ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv(outpath + "locations.csv")
```

This should concatenate all your individual csv files into one. Then you should be able to add this csv file as a delimited text layer in QGIS and set the specified CRS.
If this doesn't help would it be possible to update your question to include the adapted code you are working with?

Comment: That could work but I actually do need to keep them each separated. I ended up importing each file seaprately for now.